# Django template: localize number returned from simple tag

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5

I hope this question is not here, I have googled it for long time and not found anything. I have problem with formating numbers in templates, but somehow special. Maybe, this is whole problem how to call filters on values returned form simple tags. So, first, some facts:

- using python 2.7 and Django 1.5
- In czech language, we are using comma "," as decimal separator and optionaly space " " as thousand separator (more often is to write numbers without thousand separator).
- Normally, writing number by `{{ price }}` is printing e.g. **16,0**

For some reason, I have to work with numbers in template:

```
{% count_basic price.leafletPrice.price product.amount product.amount_unit product.category.basic_amount product.category.basic_amount_unit %}
```

count basic is simple tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def count_basic(price, product_amount, product_unit, category_amount, category_unit):
    if product_unit == 'mililiter' or product_unit == 'gram':
        return (float(price) / product_amount) * 1000
    else:
        return float(price) / product_amount
```

Result is that is't printed as **16.0**. I have set l10n in `settings.py`to True:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
```

I have also found "humanize" as working but firstly, I don't know how to call simple tag/filter with value returned from another simple tag (maybe using `with`?), secondly, if it's working for normal numbers, why not for numbers returned from simple tag? Is the number badly returned? Should be converted? I have tried also return value as `Decimal()` and not working.

Any easy working solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally, I have found out how to do this. I have changed my simple tag, specially the return part(s) to:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import floatformat

return floatformat(float(price) / product_amount, 2)
```

`floatformat` made template to display number formated, with comma as decimal separator. Two decimal places (second parameter of floatformat) was requested.